# TypeError: this.functionName is not a function

Tags: javascript, oop, typeerror

So I have created a small javascript class that is supposed to AJAX post something in a PHP file. The class is the following:

```
var cms = cms || {};

cms.load_view = (function() {
    return {
        change: function() {
            jQuery("#layout-switch a").on('click', function()
                {
                    jQuery('#layout-switch a').removeClass('current');
                    jQuery(this).addClass('current');
                    var column_number = jQuery(this).attr('data-name');
                    var category = jQuery("#cat_id").val();
                    var data = {mode: column_number, cid: category};
                    this.postChange(data);
                });
        },
        postChange: function(data) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: SITEURL + "/modules/digishop/loadcategory.php",
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        jQuery('#digishop').animate({
                            opacity: 0
                        }, 250, function () {
                            jQuery(this).addClass(column_number);
                            jQuery(this).animate({
                                opacity: 1
                            }, 250);
                        });
                    },
                    success: function (html) {
                        jQuery("#digishop").html(html);
                    }
                });
            return true;
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    cms.load_view.change();
});
```

However, when I click the selector Firebug says that `postChange` is not a function when it is called in the first method, a.k.a. `this.postChange(data);`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Inside the `click` event handler, `this` refers to the element the handler is bound to, in this case the clicked `#layout-switch a` element. Which you seem to know, since you are doing `jQuery(this).attr('data-name')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the change function, `this` is a reference to the link you clicked. Replace `this.postChange(data);` with `cms.load_view.postChange(data);`.